# transition animation on only a part of the screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation, uiimage

I am displaying two images in my iPhone app, one on top, one on the bottom. They cover the entire screen. The user, with a swipe gesture, can change either of the images, depending on where the swipe started.

I want the image to change with an animated transition. It currently works without animation, or with the entire screen transitioning. Is it possible to make the transition occur over part of the screen?

I load the images for the first time (in viewDidLoad) thus:

```
// top image
UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top1.png"];
CGRect topframe = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 240.0f);
UIImageView *topView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:topframe];
topView.image = topImage;
[self.view addSubview:topView];
[topView release];

// bottom image
UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom1.png"];
CGRect bottomframe = CGRectMake(0.0f, 240.0f, 320.0f, 240.0f);
UIImageView *bottomView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:bottomframe];
bottomView.image = bottomImage;
[self.view addSubview:bottomView];
[bottomView release];
```

When I detect a swipe, and detect which of the two images are to be changed, I call a routine like this one:

```
- (void)changeTopImage:(NSString *)newImage {
    UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageNamed:newImage];
    CGRect topframe = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 240.0f);
    UIImageView *topView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:topframe];
    topView.image = topImage;
    [self.view addSubview:topView];
    [topView release];
}
```

Essentilly, I'm continually loading images on top of each other. Is that the best way to do it, especially in terms of memory management?

Everything else I've tried, using techniques such as below, make the entire screen transition:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
...
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks for any leads on which way I should be going on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, an easy way could be this (repeat for the bottomImage):

**don't release topView** when you load it the first time in your method, 
but declare it in your .h file,
and use a tempView too:

```
@interface YourClass: UIViewController{
    UIImageView *topView;
    UIImageView *tempView;
}
```

this way you can call them to move them and remove them when you load a new image

then in .m:

**EDIT: some correction (see coco's comments):**

[a]  [b] line 4 =  [c] line 11:

```
- (void)changeTopImage:(NSString *)newImage {
    UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageNamed:newImage];
    //CGRect topframe = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, (320.0f + 320), 240.0f);
    CGRect topframe = CGRectMake((0.0f + 320), 0.0f, 320.0f, 240.0f);
    tempView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:topframe];
    //topView.image = topImage;
    tempView.image = topImage;
    [self.view addSubview:tempView];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
                tempView.center = topView.center;
                // do this to push old topView away, comment next line if wanna new image just cover it
                //topView.center =  CGPointMake(topView.x - 320, topView.y);
                topView.center = CGPointMake(topView.center.x - 320, topView.center.y);
                // call a method when animation has finished:
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(endOfAnimation:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

    - (void)endOfAnimation:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context{

        [topView removeFromSuperview];
        topView = tempView;
        [tempView release];
        tempView = nil;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    }

- (void)dealloc {
    if (tempView != nil) {
        [tempView release];
    }
    [topView release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Cool! Some changes, and a question: [a] CGRect topframe = CGRectMake((0.0f + 320), 0.0f, 320.0f, 240.0f); [b] line 4 = tempView.image = topImage; [c] line 11: topView.center =  CGPointMake(topView.center.x - 320, topView.center.y); [d] my question: why is topView removed from the superview?? It works fine if I don't do that, and it doesn't logically make sense to me.. Thanks for this

Comment: if you don't it will just be covered (if not moved to left) or moved away, so you won't see it, but that doesn't mean that it won't exist. You have to remove it to "kill" it, or you'll have a lot of images if you continue to add images... the goal is to have just 2 images on screen, you don't need to keep the old images... so my code do this: use a temp-image for the animation (the only case when you have 3 images on screen), at the end you remove the old image (topView), then let pointer topView to point to the newImg (tempImg). Now you have 2 pointer pointing to newImg, y can "kill" tempImg.

Comment: and if you don't wanna release and keep it/them in memory, well, then you had not to do all that code to swap some images... you could do that just using 2 UIScrollView (1 top and one bottom) and putting images inside them, side-by-side, it was an easy way, bit i though you were looking for an virtually infinity image-loader, so you neen to release memory everytime... ...and for your changes: yes, you are right, of course... sorry and tks... i'll take the time to correct them with a new Edit...